# What is the expected Robin Hood Hashing maximum probe sequence length?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have read that worst case is `log2(n)` for a table of size `n` with `n` keys, but my experimental results show a vastly different average longest probe sequence. For example, with `n=1<<16`, I see an average maximum of 315--not 16.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of keys will depend heavily on the hash function. If many items hash to the same position, then those items will form a long chain, and that might be why your tests diverge from the theoretical results.

You should also be aware of how complexities are presented. When you say something grow as log2(n), one interpretation is that it's O(log2(n)), which means that the curve is within a constant factor of log2(n) as n grows. Plot your findings along a curve together with log2(n) and see if the ratio remains constant.